# How can I handle a Julian Date rollover in SQL?

Tags: sql, julian-date

I have a list of julian dates that I need to keep in order ex. 362, 363, 364, 365, 001, 002, 003. My query starts with getting the last julian date processed and each date after that. Right now it will max my lowest date out at 365 and I can't get the records that follow it. The same set of data also has a date field with the year attached but it doesn't seem to be helpful since those records won't be gathered until the rollover is corrected. Here is my simplified query:

```
select JulianDate, RecordDate 
from table 
where JulianField > @LowestJulianDate
and RecordDate between GetDate() and DateAdd(day, 6, GetDate())
```

Sample date:

| JulianDate | RecordDate |
| --- | --- |
| 362 | 2020-12-28 |
| 363 | 2020-12-29 |
| 364 | 2020-12-30 |
| 365 | 2020-12-31 |
| 001 | 2021-01-01 |
| 002 | 2021-01-02 |
| 003 | 2021-01-03 |

Desired output:

| JulianDate |
| --- |
| 362 |
| 363 |
| 364 |
| 365 |
| 001 |
| 002 |
| 003 |

So if you'll imagine we start on day 362, our @LowestJulianDate is 362, and our record date range is today and the next 6 days, completing that list of julian dates.

How can I get the dates to go in order and resolve in a rollover?

Comment: `362` doesn't look like a date to me.  And it definitely doesn't look compatible with what `getdate()` returns.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Julian date is the numbered day of the year, a range that goes from 001 to 365. So if the julian date was 362 then the actual date would be 2020-12-28 and the date range that I've listed would go to 2021-01-03. The returned data would be the list of julian dates and the actual dates.

Comment: . . Sample data and desired results would clarify the question.

Comment: A  Julian date as used by the military includes the year. This used to be 5 digits with year as the first 2 digits but since 2000 the year should be 4 digits followed by the 3 digit DayOfYear number.

Comment: Can I suggest you have a look at the description for the julian-date tag (and click the learn more link)... I don't think you are working with julian dates. Not that this helps you directly, except that you might get more relevant answers if you tag the question correctly. Others seem to be confused too.

Comment: It might be simplest to convert the value representing your date to a SQL `DATE`, do whatever processing, then convert the result back to your TYPE.

Comment: You are right, I had an incorrect definition of the julian date. Now that I'm looking at my data more closely I can see that this problem is more complex than I thought. The idea of adding the year to the date and ordering by that may be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot by just using the "JulianDate" which is actually the DayOfYear value. You would need to also store the year that it refers to either separately or as part of the "JulianDate" value. For example, instead of "362"  you need "2021362".

Comment: In a roundabout way this was the solution. Basically I needed to tack on the record date's year in a separate field and then order the data by that. Thank you for leading me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

well why not sorting by year column and Julian date column ?

```
select JulianDate, RecordDate 
from table 
order by yearcolumn,JulianDate
```

Comment: Given the query I've provided, that wouldn't work. If I start with the lowest julian date then no record can be shown below that. Ordering by the record date's year wouldn't change that. The answer I'm looking for would have to change how the lowest julian date is used to get the list. Like listing the record numbers then setting the lowest julian date's record number to be the starting point. 

I think I'm actually going to try that.

Comment: I'm not following , instead explain your original problem and also provide sample data and desired output

Comment: also Julian date is just day of year  , is not a real date , so when you look for `JulianField > @LowestJulianDate` how do you know to start from which year??

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing in the case of not having a year and wanting to sort a list on the year rollover for a 7 day rolling window is looking at the left 1 of the Julian day. If it's less than 3 roll it's rolled over. We sort into 2 baskets (old year and new year), order them, then recombine them with the new year's data being the "greatest" in the list.

We look at the left 1 because in our application, the last day of data we get may be 357 and the rollover may be 003 for example.